# How do I unquote in Quora?

Tags: quora

There is a "quote" formatting option within Quora, but no "unquote" to undo the deeper quote level. How do I unquote text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to "unquote" to undo the deeper quote level in Quora.